# Strange maven version ranges in versions-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, version, versions-maven-plugin

I have see ranges from [1.1,2.0) or [1.1,)
but what does this mean:

```
  <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>security-api</name>
                                <version>[1.4,1.4.1-!)</version>
                            </property>
```

Is this `-!` within `[1.4,1.4.1-!)` specific for version-maven-plugin and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclamation mark in `[1.4,1.4.1-!)` is there to prevent `1.4.1-SNAPSHOT` version (and other similar, like `-alpha`) to be used, as `[1.4,1.4.1)` would allow `1.4.1-SNAPSHOT` to be used.

**But**, using Maven 3.5.0 at least, that `[1.4,1.4.1-!)` range will also allow `1.4.1` to be used.

It is working like this for, in ASCII, `!` is anyway lower than `A`

Comment: But what about 1.4.2 is it part of the range? or 1.4.1.1

Comment: Both won't resolve, but 1.4.1 will (edited answer to show that).

Comment: OK But how to trigger this property to be get?

Comment: This seems to be a configuration item for the `versions-maven-plugin`. I don't think you will be able to use it outside of that plugin.

Comment: Yes ,yes but if I execute mvn clean install does the right version will be get?

Comment: It will update the `security-api` property with a version fulfilling your range restrictions. But the exact value will depend on the rest of the configuration for this property.